# ¿Usar index.php vacío en directorios?

Tags: php, prestashop

Habitualmente coloco un fichero **index.php** vacío en todos los directorios de los aplicaciones que desarrollos en PHP, excepto cuando necesito poner código en este fichero claro. Según tengo entendido es la forma de evitar, en caso de acceso mediante navegador web, que se listen los ficheros y directorios que contiene, de ocultar el contenido. He visto que en *PrestaShop*, éstos **index.php** redireccionan al directorio "padre", lo que cumple una función, pero también incluyen varios headers:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Location: ../");
exit;
```

La pregunta es: ¿Es recomendable incluir "headers" de algún tipo en los ficheros que uso vacíos y que función cumplirían en caso afirmativo?

Comment: No soy un experto pero creo que esos headers son por seguridad. Dejar un archivo php vacío puede darte muchos problemas de seguridad.

Answer (score 2):

### A. Evitar que los directorios / archivos sean listados

Para evitar que los ficheros de un directorio sean listados existe un método más práctico, más eficaz y más seguro.

Puedes proceder de dos maneras, de acuerdo a la configuración de tu sistema y tus necesidades.

1. Bloquear el listado de archivos / directorios / subdirectorios desde el mismo directrio.

   Basta con poner esto en el archivo `.htaccess`del directorio que quieres bloquear:

   **`Options -Indexes`**

   De este modo **no se podrá listar nada de ese directorio ni de sus subdirectorios** y te evitas de paso tener que ir creando archivos `index.php` por todas partes.
2. Si necesitas una configuración más restrictiva, en la cual no quieres que ningún directorio de tu sitio se pueda listar, puedes bloquear esta opción desde el archivo `httpd.conf` de la siguiente forma:

   Buscar en `httpd.conf` una línea parecida a esta y remover la palabra `Indexes` :

   `Options Includes` <s>Indexes</s> `FollowSymLinks MultiViews`

   Quedaría así:

   `Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews`

   Y si quieres habilitar el listado de archivos / directorios para algún directorio en particular, puedes sobreescribir lo indicado en `httpd.conf` escribiendo lo siguiente en el archivo `.htaccess` del directorio en cuestión:

   **`Options +Indexes`**

> **Nota:** El manejo del archivo `.htaccess`es bastante delicado, un simple error en él como un caracter de más o de menos, podría el sitio totalmente fuera de línea mientras persista el error.

### B. Archivo index.php

Si sólo usas archivos del tipo `index.php` para evitar el listado de directorios, aplicando lo dicho en **(A)** ya tienes resuelto ese problema. Y puedes usar `index.php` sólo si tienes alguna necesidad especial.

En mi caso yo tengo, en un sitio manejado por Wordpress, un solo archivo `index.php` en el directorio raíz (es la configuración WP por defecto). Luego este archivo re-envía a la plantilla de WP del siguiente modo:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Y en el `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Luego, en algunas carpetas WP coloca archivos `index.php` solo con esto:

```
<?php
// Silence is golden.
```

No aparece nada de headers en dicho archivo y las carpetas donde WP los pone, son aquellas que almacenan contenido, como `wp-content`, donde se guardan las imágenes, los plugins, etc.

Si por algún motivo necesitas aparte de tu sitio dedicar una carpeta a algo en específico, puedes crear allí tu archivo `index.php` y hacer las redirecciones de lugar. De hecho, en una parte de mi sitio tengo  una servicio REST en cuya carpeta de entrada hay un `index.php` que controla todo el flujo de entrada a esa carpeta, y funciona como algo totalmente independiente del sitio web.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple es lo que estás haciendo, también puedes poner el header location si quieres redireccionar a algún lado. Incluso un index.html vacío también sirve.
Eso más un buen .htaccess es bastante seguro.